# Private Clique network, where can I get block sealer and block reward?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, blocks, geth-clique

- Private blockchain
- PoA validation algorithm

Using `geth attach MY-GETH-CLIENT`, I want to check the sealer of a block as well as its reward.

---

Using `eth.getBlock(BLOCK-NUMBER)`, the miner field is sometimes equal to 0x00...0:

```
    > eth.getBlock('216567')
    {
      difficulty: 2,
      extraData: "0xd883010907846765746888676f312e31332e34856c696e757800000000000000a5d63126675c1b8f9811e995dd8cb5276486a64b06ad590a542c74aea142b68a64abc2f5bbd1ba3b10adfa8200ce678961b22c724f4eca81ba1bb770942c7d6e01",
      gasLimit: 8000000,
      gasUsed: 0,
      hash: "0xed19228537c738101308a08811c4232ca72176efa55a498f7286ef915be854f0",
      logsBloom: "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",      
      miner: "0x9a9ee44782accc4b5e893c0e7d16473ce19b79d6",
      mixHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      nonce: "0xffffffffffffffff",
      number: 216567,
      parentHash: "0x1f80f98bfa571053745d99146f2665a2a69004e8134cc750ba94b17bd2fd5639",
      receiptsRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
      sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
      size: 609,
      stateRoot: "0xe2236887f5f873fd7e4a12ba8e6bbf10ab6b2c70adcba3488bb6e9c9e89b1151",
      timestamp: 1577436727,
      totalDifficulty: 433020,
      transactions: [],
      transactionsRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
      uncles: []
    }
    > eth.getBlock('216568')
    {
     properties,   
      miner: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
Some more properties
    }
```

Checking the balance of the address `0x9a9ee44782accc4b5e893c0e7d16473ce19b79d6` returns 0:

```
> eth.getBalance('0x9a9ee44782accc4b5e893c0e7d16473ce19b79d6')
0
```

---

I've read [here](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225) that the sealer address should be in the extra data, but which part is it in the following extradata (from block 216567 above) ?

```
extraData: "0xd883010907846765746888676f312e31332e34856c696e757800000000000000a5d63126675c1b8f9811e995dd8cb5276486a64b06ad590a542c74aea142b68a64abc2f5bbd1ba3b10adfa8200ce678961b22c724f4eca81ba1bb770942c7d6e01",
```

---

**How can I get, in PoA, the sealer of a block and how can I know the block reward ?**

PS: I have access to the following modules in geth:  `admin:1.0 clique:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PoA networks do not natively have rewards baked into the consensus. There are instances where these are created with smart contracts that make system calls (see Energy Web Chain and POS_DAO) , but if you run clique natively there will be no block rewards.

#### References:

- [EIP 225](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-225)
- [POS DAO](https://github.com/poanetwork/posdao-contracts)
- [Energy Web Chain - System Contracts - Rewards Contract](https://github.com/energywebfoundation/ewc-system-contracts#reward-contract)

Comment: Finally an explicit answer about this. Thanks. Then the quantity of ether in the network is finite, right ? The network is condemned to no longer be functional after an amount of time (can be very very long, but still at the very end ...)

Comment: For clique? Or with the reward model? The security model is not premised on block incentives so they aren’t native. The block chain can continue to function for as long as you need it too. Incentives are not built into the consensus layer and if you need to add them, they have to be done at the application /smart contract level. Hope it makes sense

Comment: I'll come back when I've read the sources you gave me ;)